# Laravel how to block or secure id in route

Tags: laravel, routes

i have custom password reset in my project where user can change his password, now how can i secure the route where the user cannot manipulate the id..does laravel has it in the middleware?

**Example:**`http://localhost:8000/changepassword/1/edit` if user attempt to changes the **id** parameter it will redirect to access denied page.. is this possible?

Comment: Yes possible, you can check the Login user id and the user-id which you get from URL

Comment: then if im going to emplement that, what will happen to the default admin? how can he change the password of others..

Comment: You can check for the admin user that, if the user is admin or user-id is equal to login user id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it is possible**

In your controller function, you can check the current/login user id and that id which you are going to get from the URL

Also for admin user you can add one condition that

```
if(ADMINUSER || LOGIN_USER_ID == URL_ID){

}
```

But I **recommend** that add an extra column with the random and unique string use that column instead of Id, In that case your URL will be like this

/changepassword/wcdftgHYuj346DERFD/edit

then you need to get the user on the base of random_string 'wcdftgHYuj346DERFD'

Comment: yes i like this suggestion i ddnt know that randon string can be use as id field in the url

Comment: So meaning every time i create new user it will send also random string then when the time i pull out the id ill retrieve the string column together?

Comment: Yes, while adding new user add the random_string with it, and retrieve it while you need it.

Comment: so inside my route i can use get:('test/{randomstring}') i can use this? as the parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can add this

Comment: last question how to auto generate random string? in my controller can show me example if possible?

Comment: There are alot of example on stack and other websites, you can check this question ps://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304930/how-can-i-create-a-unique-random-string-in-laravel-5

Comment: okay thanks man for ur answer and idea now i now this will help me secure my site hehe thanks